# How install GTK 4 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gtk

On the site [gtk.org](http://gtk.org) i see version 4.0 and:

1. I installed MSYS2 following the instructions ([gtk.org/docs/installations/windows](http://gtk.org/docs/installations/windows))
2. Then I installed the `pacman-S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4 package`
3. And installed Glade `pacman-S mingw-w64-x86_64-glade`
4. Then I installed all this in python `pacman-S mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject`

But at startup, it writes that the GTK version is `3.24.24-1`
Or maybe I can install GTK4 using pip
(I use Windows 10 and Pycharm with python 3.7)